# Building multiple images from a monorepo where each service has its own Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-service

I'm attempting to learn Azure DevOps Pipelines and AKS. The ultimate goal would to [Build and deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/aks-template?view=azure-devops), but I'm breaking this into smaller parts so understand what is going on at each stage.

Thus, my current goal is to [Build and push to Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops).

I'm working with a pretty basic monorepo which has this simplified structure:

```
acr-test/
  client/
    Dockerfile
  db/
    Dockerfile
  server/
    Dockerfile
```

I'd like to generate an image for each part of the application so that a `arc-test-client` and `arc-test-server` is generated.

What is currently happening when I "Create Pipeline" in Azure DevOps and let it build the `azure-pipelines.yml` is it just finds the first `Dockerfile` and bases all the parameters on it, ignoring the other ones.

Some I'm curious:

- Is it possible to create multiple images from a single `azure-pipelines.yml`?
- Do I need multiple `.yml` for each `Dockerfile`?
- Do I need to write a separate `.sh` to build and push these separately ([example](https://github.com/StephenGrider/DockerCasts/blob/master/complex/deploy.sh))?
- Or is this simply not possible with a mono-repo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. yes, you'd need to modify the `azure-pipelines.yml` for that.
2. no. one for all or one for each dockerfile is okay
3. not necessary, you could use a `.sh` script, but probably easier to just have docker tasks in the `azure-pipelines.yml`
4. it is.

you would need to do something like this:

```
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository1)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath1)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag1)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository2)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath2)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag2)
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository3)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath3)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag3)
```

or can have multiple `something.yml` in the repo and have individual builds for each component (makes a lot more sense, tbh)

alternatively, with your file structure you can just reuse the same yaml file as a template and just feed it parameters. that would reduce code duplication and allow for easier management of your builds

Comment: So can we build same images via docker-compose.yml in same way ?